# Timer starts over when next_question selected

Tags: flutter, timer

I'm making a quiz app using Flutter.
I have created a timer of 30 seconds which should start when a new question comes up.

[image]

It works fine and it restarts after the next question comes.
**But when I click on "Next Question" without choosing an option, it restarts the timer.**
I have created that button in such a way that you cannot go to the next question without choosing an option first.

Code:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    starttimer();
    _questions = getData();
    super.initState();
  }

  int index = 0;
  int score = 0;
  bool isPressed = false;
  bool isAlreadySelected = false;
  int timer = 30;
  String showtimer = "30";
  bool canceltimer = false;

  void starttimer() async {
    const onesec = Duration(seconds: 1);
    Timer.periodic(onesec, (Timer t) {
      setState(() {
        if (timer < 1) {
          t.cancel();
          nextQuestion(index++);
        } else if (canceltimer == true) {
          t.cancel();
        } else {
          timer = timer - 1;
        }
        showtimer = timer.toString();
      });
    });
  }

  void nextQuestion(int questionLength) {
    canceltimer = false;
    timer = 30;
    if (index == 19 || score == 12) {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          barrierDismissible: false,
          builder: (ctx) => ResultBox(
                result: score,
                questionLength: questionLength,
              ));
    } else {
      if (isPressed) {
        setState(() {
          index++;
          isPressed = false;
          isAlreadySelected = false;
          starttimer();
        });
      
      } else {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: const Text('Please select any option'),
          behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
        ));
        starttimer();
      }
    }
  }

  void checkAnswerAndUpdate(bool value) {
    if (isAlreadySelected) {
      return;
    } else {
      if (value == true) {
        score++;
        setState(() {
          isPressed = true;
          isAlreadySelected = false;
          canceltimer = true;
        });
      } else if (value == false) {
        setState(() {
          isPressed = true;
          isAlreadySelected = false;
          canceltimer = true;
        });
      }
    }
  }

void startOver() {
    setState(() {
      Text('You have already attempted the LL Test');
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _questions as Future<List<Question>>,
      builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: Text('${snapshot.error}'),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            var extractedData = snapshot.data as List<Question>;
            return Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: background,
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: const Text('LL Test'),
                backgroundColor: background,
                shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
                actions: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Score: $score',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              body: Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    // Countdown(
                    //   animation: StepTween(begin: limitTime, end: 0)
                    //       .animate(_controller),
                    // ),
                    QuestionWidget(
                      question: extractedData[index].title,
                      indexAction: index,
                      totalQuestions: extractedData.length,
                    ),
                    const Divider(
                      color: neutral,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 25.0),
                    for (int i = 0;
                        i < extractedData[index].options.length;
                        i++)
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () => checkAnswerAndUpdate(
                            extractedData[index].options.values.toList()[i]),
                        child: OptionCard(
                          option: extractedData[index].options.keys.toList()[i],
                          color: isPressed
                              ? extractedData[index]
                                          .options
                                          .values
                                          .toList()[i] ==
                                      true
                                  ? correct
                                  : incorrect
                              : neutral,
                        ),
                      ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            showtimer,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 40.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                              fontFamily: 'Times New Roman',
                              color: neutral,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              floatingActionButton: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => nextQuestion(extractedData.length),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                  child: NextButton(),
                ),
              ),
              floatingActionButtonLocation:
                  FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
            );
          }
        } else {
          return Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                CircularProgressIndicator(),
                SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                Text(
                  'Please Wait While Questions Are Loading..',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 4, 82, 6),
                      color: neutral),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }

        return const Center(
          child: Text('NoData'),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Is it something wrong in my code? What should I do so that timer doesn't startover?

Answer (score 0):

did you call the `starttimer()` inside else condition?
try to remove it.

```
      } else {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: const Text('Please select any option'),
          behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
        ));
       // starttimer();  this call the function even its not selected yet
      }
```

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem. I have called it there so that timer starts again on the next question when I don't press the button and the time is up

Comment: now thats the problem,
you have to add new condition for that case. when times up, then next question and start timer,

Comment: Can you tell in the code what condition I have to write?